# How to handle switch widget (or button) outside RecyclerView in activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, switch-statement, android-cardview

I have recyclerview with cardview to load data and there are two columns, the code work fine but I need to hide the first column with switch widget. I have trying some code but none work for me. Can someone help me. I'm new in android. Thanks

Here is the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Below is my code

**MyFragment.java**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, viewGroup, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mobile = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mobile);
        desktop = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.desktop);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // this code below didn't work. i thought it's because different 
        // layout between fragment and adapter but i don't know to solve it
        final TextView tvMobile = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_mobile);
        Switch mSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switch_item);
        mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    tvMobile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    tvMobile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public static String[] mobile;
    public static String[] desktop;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cardview, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvMobile.setText(mobile[position]);
        holder.tvDesktop.setText(desktop[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mobile.length;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvMobile;
        private TextView tvDesktop;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvMobile = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_mobile);
            tvDesktop = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desktop);
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_recyclerview.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#dfe7f2"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Hide Mobile Row"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/color_divider" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_cardview.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background_dark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card_view" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_mobile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="romaji"
            android:textColor="@color/black_1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_desktop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="arti"
            android:textColor="@color/black_1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In your adapter change like this**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

public static boolean isMobileHided = false; //add this flag

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvMobile.setText(mobile[position]);
    holder.tvDesktop.setText(desktop[position]);
    if (isMobileHided) {
        holder.tvMobile.setVisblity(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        holder.tvMobile.setVisblity(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
}
```

**In your switch listener(From activity/fragments)**

```
 mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           //update the switch button status to adapter flag variable
           adapter.isMobileHided = isChecked;
           //refresh the adapter
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: work sir, thanks. so every change the ViewHolder should use this method notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: yes we need to use notifyDataSetChanged() for each update. pls put tick mark for this answer if this ans works

Comment: @RanjithKumar thank you man you saved me from so much headache! haha! :D